# printing a formatted string inside a variable

Tags: c, string, pointers, c-strings

So I have a char pointer p:

```
int num = 1;
char *p = ""This is a formatted string with a number %d",num"";
```

How  can I print p so the output will be:
"This is a formatted string with a number 1"

Comment: use `sprintf` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm

Comment: I'll rather recommend [`snprint`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to avoid possible buffer overruns.

Comment: Unrelated: Even though it's legal to make `p` a `char*` I recommend making it a `const char*` since you aren't allowed to change the string it's pointing at.